# Watching any video in Chrome has red boxes

Tags: video, google-chrome, youtube

FIXED:
Version 53.0.2785.89 (64-bit) fixed it

OLD:
I've been noticing this for the last couple months, but whenever I watch a video in chrome (Version 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit)) I see small red boxes over the video. The boxes jump around and flicker. It doesn't matter which site it is for (screenshot is youtube and steam)

Things I've tried:

1. It does not happen in safari
2. chrome://flags/#disable-accelerated-video-decode (disabled)
3. chrome://flags/#disable-cast-streaming-hw-encoding (disabled)
4. chrome://flags/#enable-webrtc-h264-with-openh264-ffmpeg (disabled)

￼[image: Red boxes in youtube]
[image: red boxes in steam]
[image: System description]

Comment: What Chrome version ar you using?

Comment: @root Version 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit)

Comment: actually it just updated to Version 53.0.2785.89 (64-bit) and now its fine. Oh well thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 53.0.2785.89 (64-bit) fixed it